# CRM : Show all notes on the form instead of lazy-loading

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, lazy-loading, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Dynamics CRM 365 by default demonstrates only limited amount of notes on the note block of entity form. In my case it is 10 notes. The rest notes are supposed to be 'lazy loaded' when user scrolls notes down. Somehow this feature is broken, notes are not loaded.

[image]

Nothing interesting neither in the console, nor in the server's event log. This is complete freakage.

**Is there any option to load all notes simultaneously, like in old CRM 2011?**

Or maybe anyone can advise how to investigate this issue?

---

**UPDATE:** 
Just checked this issue with tracing tool on 'Warning' level and here's what it shows when I try to load notes:

```
[2017-07-06 08:39:43.344] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   39 |Category: Exception |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 055f8ace-5e77-4c01-b980-0e97088ed4aa |ActivityId: 055f8ace-5e77-4c01-b980-0e97088ed4aa | CrmHttpException..ctor  ilOffset = 0x22
    at CrmHttpException..ctor(HttpStatusCode statusCode, String message, Object[] args)  ilOffset = 0x22
    at CrmODataOptimisticConcurrencyHelper.HandleGetMatchETags(CrmODataExecutionContext context, Entity entity)  ilOffset = 0x129
    at CrmODataServiceDataProvider.RetrieveEntityWithRelatedRecords(CrmODataExecutionContext context, EntityReference primaryEntityReference, QueryExpression qe, RelationshipQueryCollection relatedEntitiesQuery)  ilOffset = 0x19
    at CrmODataServiceDataProvider.RetrieveEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, String entityKeyValue, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)  ilOffset = 0x2D
    at EntityController.GetEntity(String entityName, String key)  ilOffset = 0x32
    at   ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at <>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x34
    at <InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()  ilOffset = 0x52
    at AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine)  ilOffset = 0x2C
    at ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x35
    at ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x3
    at <ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()  ilOffset = 0xD9
    at AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine)  ilOffset = 0x2C
    at ActionFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x35
    at ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x138
    at <SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()  ilOffset = 0x123
    at AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine)  ilOffset = 0x2C
    at HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x3D
    at HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x3C
    at HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0xBF
    at DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x19
    at <SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()  ilOffset = 0x17D
    at AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine)  ilOffset = 0x2C
    at CorsMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x3D
    at DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x19
    at <SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()  ilOffset = 0x50
    at AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine)  ilOffset = 0x2C
    at CrmETagMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x3D
    at DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x19
    at <SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()  ilOffset = 0xF
    at AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine)  ilOffset = 0x2C
    at CrmDelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x3D
    at DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x19
    at <SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()  ilOffset = 0x11D
    at AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine)  ilOffset = 0x2C
    at HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x3D
    at HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  ilOffset = 0x3C
    at <ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()  ilOffset = 0x96
    at AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine)  ilOffset = 0x2C
    at HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore(HttpContextBase contextBase)  ilOffset = 0x2C
    at TaskAsyncHelper.BeginTask(Func`1 taskFunc, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)  ilOffset = 0xD
    at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  ilOffset = 0xE6
    at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)  ilOffset = 0x3C
    at PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)  ilOffset = 0x27A
    at HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)  ilOffset = 0x31
    at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)  ilOffset = 0xB0
    at PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)  ilOffset = 0x131
    at PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)  ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)  ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)  ilOffset = 0x1E7
    at PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)  ilOffset = 0x0
>Crm Exception: Message: The requested record matches a specified If-None-Match version., ErrorCode: -2147088246
[2017-07-06 08:39:43.344] Process: w3wp |Organization:3eb43172-29f4-dd11-80b4-0015178dc928 |Thread:   39 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 055f8ace-5e77-4c01-b980-0e97088ed4aa |ActivityId: 055f8ace-5e77-4c01-b980-0e97088ed4aa | CrmODataUtilities.Trace  ilOffset = 0x24
>{"Error":{"InnerError":null,"Message":"CrmHttpException: The requested record matches a specified If-None-Match version."}}
```

Comment: I'd try to recreate the issue in a vanilla organization to see if it's a problem that only happens in your organization or a platform bug (in this case I'd raise it to MS support team).

Comment: @FedericoJousset I've run tracing tool and it shows me kind of exception, see update.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I haven't faced that error before and the information about it is not very good. The web service error codes describes it as "A failure occurred in Wep Api in Dynamics 365." and it probably it's related to the request that CRM is creating (with the If-None-Match header) to query the notes. You can try to obtain the request being generated using Fiddler to see if you spot the error but I'd raise it as a bug to MS support team.

Comment: @R.Matveev Can you please confirm if the problem exists for all entities or only CASE entity??   Could be that some notes have attachments of very large size.....

Comment: @Dot_NETPro, replied to you in the answer as the problem is solved. It was by my imprudence as I disabled one of system functions long ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@Dot_NETPro, now the problem is solved.

The root was in the Activity Feeds system `renderOlderPosts` function, as we disabled it in previous update pack because it have been raising null reference exception (because of the MS bug) on the page for all users. The function haven't seemed to be used by the CRM, but in the next update pack it started to render the comments. Also, null reference exception is fixd for now in the latest update pack.